# Draw chart with multiple data series

Tags: excel, vba

I want to plot a chart from multiple data series of a table. To have a single data series, i.e to plot B against A I use below code:

```
Sub plt()
    Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A,B:B")
    With ActiveSheet
      .Shapes.AddChart
      Set objChrt = .ChartObjects(.ChartObjects.Count)
      Set chrt = objChrt.Chart
      With chrt
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
        .SetSourceData Source:=rng1
     End With
   End With   
End Sub
```

Now I want to plot C column against D column in the same chart. 
I tries to modify the rng a

```
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A,B:B, C:C,D:D")
```

but it does not work. can anyone help me please?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try replacing your last three lines with:

```
          .PlotArea.Select
          End With
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("C:C")
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = ActiveSheet.Range("D:D")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: is it possible to do that with set range?  i want to add legend.